# Fresh OS X Ruby on Rails Install Failing To Connect To Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'll preface by giving my specs:

- RVM 1.12.1
- Rails 3.2.3
- Ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]
- RubyGem 1.8.21
- OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
- Kenneth Reitz's GCC Installer for OSX 10.7+, Version 2 (includes X11 headers, bugfixes)

My Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And my database.yml is:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

When I start the server and go to the default homepage and click the "view environment" button, I get an "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished" error.

When I check the console, I see:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
```

Despite the fact that I'm using SQLite and that there is no reference to MySQL anywhere.  Could this possibly be a side effect of some sort of using 10.8?  I'm stumped!

Comment: Are you sure there's no references to `mysql` anywhere in your app, even somewhere sneaky? Everything there looks okay.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  This is a fresh, out of the box Rails install.

Comment: How are you starting the rails server?

Comment: It could be trying to start the server in production mode or something. Try rails s -e development (or look into what your RAILS_ENV environment variables i)

Comment: Both 'rails s' and 'rails s -e development' yield the same result as  above.

Comment: Are there any references to `mysql` or `mysql2` in Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few months ago I was working on a project using java and Play! Framework, and we used an environment variable called DATABASE_URL to manage the database config easily on development and production. In my case the variable was set to `mysql://root@localhost:3306/database_name`.

As it turns out, `rails 3.2` tries to get database configuration from an environment variable called DATABASE_URL too.

Here is the code on rails 3.2 branch:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb#L91-135

The same method on rails 3.1 branch:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb#L23-82

So I just removed the environment variable and everything is normal again.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the exact issue that was plaguing me as well.  I'm surprised that we both had this specific of an issue.  Great find!